# How can I make this kind of list view within layout?

Tags: android

I'v just implemented side drawer menu to my App.
Then I have new layout for it.

But I don't know how to design this kind of stylish list view.

[image: List menu]

How can I make this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list should be this way:

1. Header 1 (View with Photo and Name)
2. Header 2 (View with Features- This should be a separate layout as the no of items are going to be fixed)
3. The list of messages

Comment: Thanks! What about image? I found I can use Android's icon as default something like `ic_dialog_email` these should be in Strings.xml? or layout's xml?